# Combine count(distinct) with complicate select condition mysql

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have two working mysql select statements which I'd like to combine:

```
SELECT 
    t2.*, 
    t1.Lang, 
    Filmname, 
    ColFI 
FROM Timetable t2, Contenttable t1 
WHERE DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201825',' Thursday'), '%x%v %W'), INTERVAL 0 DAY) = DateSZ 
    AND RoomSZ =1 AND t2.idFI = t1.id 
    AND deleteSZ = false 
ORDER BY TimeSZ
```

giving me (and of course some other irrelevant columns) for a specific day:

```
+----------+-------+------+------+------------+
| Filmname | time  | idFI | Lang | DateSZ     |
+----------+-------+------+------+------------+
| firstfi  | 12:00 | 22   | eng  | 2018-06-29 |
+----------+-------+------+------+------------+
| sencofi  | 15:00 | 44   | fra  | 2018-06-29 |
```

second:

```
SELECT 
    idFI, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT (case when Yweek < 201825 then Yweek end)) AS Week 
FROM `Timetable` 
GROUP BY idFI
```

giving me

```
+-------+------+
| Week  | idFI |
+-------+------+
| 2     | 22   |
+-------+------+
| 1     | 44   |
```

My Timetable table is looking somewhat like this (plus some more columns):

```
+----------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| Filmname | time  | idFI | Yweek  | DateSZ     |
+----------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| firstfi  | 12:00 | 22   | 201825 | 2018-06-29 |
+----------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| firstfi  | 18:00 | 22   | 201824 | 2018-06-21 |
+----------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| firstfi  | 13:00 | 22   | 201823 | 2018-06-12 | 
+----------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| sencofi  | 15:00 | 44   | 201825 | 2018-06-29 |
+----------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| sencofi  | 18:00 | 44   | 201823 | 2018-06-12 |
+----------+-------+------+--------+------------+
| sencofi  | 10:00 | 44   | 201823 | 2018-06-13 |
```

My problem is, that if I insert the count(distinct) into the first select statement, it isn't working because it only counts rows witch meets all the where clauses in statement nr. 1. How can I combine these statements?

Edit:
Answer from @MKhalidJunaid, but not working with my formatting:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.Lang, Filmname, ColFI, t3.Week DATE_FORMAT(DateSZ, '%d.%m.%y') AS DateSZ, TIME_FORMAT(TimeSZ, '%H:%i') AS TimeSZ
FROM Timetable t2
JOIN Contenttable t1 ON t2.idFI = t1.id
JOIN (
    SELECT idFI, COUNT(DISTINCT (case when Yweek < 201825 then Yweek end)) AS Week 
    FROM Timetable 
    GROUP BY idFI
) t3 ON t2.idFI = t3.idFI
WHERE DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201825',' Thursday'), '%x%v %W'), INTERVAL 0 DAY) = DateSZ 
AND RoomSZ =1 
AND deleteSZ = false 
ORDER BY TimeSZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a derived sub select for your count query and then join with your first query as

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.Lang, Filmname, ColFI , t3.Week
FROM Timetable t2
JOIN Contenttable t1 ON t2.idFI = t1.id
JOIN (
    SELECT idFI, COUNT(DISTINCT (case when Yweek < 201825 then Yweek end)) AS Week 
    FROM Timetable 
    GROUP BY idFI
) t3 ON t2.idFI = t3.idFI
WHERE DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201825',' Thursday'), '%x%v %W'), INTERVAL 0 DAY) = DateSZ 
AND RoomSZ =1 
AND deleteSZ = false 
ORDER BY TimeSZ
```

Also don't use old syntax for joining tables use explicit syntax using join keyword

Comment: Thank you! Please note I only have two mysql tables. Why are you using t3?

Comment: Sub-queries require an alias. t3 is for the sub-query.

Comment: @NIck `t3` is an alias for derived sub select which is your count query

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! If I try to add date and time formatting after "t3.Week" it isn't working. Do you have a clue what I'm doing wrong? DATE_FORMAT(DateSZ, '%d.%m.%y') AS DateSZ, TIME_FORMAT(TimeSZ, '%H:%i') AS TimeSZ

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(DateSZ, '%d.%m.%y') AS DateSZ, TIME_FORMAT(TimeSZ, '%H:%i') AS TimeSZ FROM Ti' at line 1

Comment: @NIck It looks like you a syntax error, To get clear picture can you post complete query in your question or you could ask a new one

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid just added it to my question.

Comment: @NIck you missed a comma after `t3.Week`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid A shame I didn't recognized it by myself. Thank you very much for your help!